# Facebook like with FB.Event.subscribe

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like, fbml

I currently have a like button on my app and I need to detect when this is clicked so that I can trigger some javascript.

Currently I use this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {});
```

In order for this to work you must use the FBML version of the like button. It does not work with the HTML5 version.

I am wondering what the situation will be from Jan 1st when FBML is deprecated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML and xFBML aren't the same thing.

xFBML is used to add buttons easily to web pages.
FBML was a language used to develop canvas apps.

If FBML is deprecated, xFBML isn't planned to be removed !

> Please Note: Our deprecation of FBML does not impact XFBML (eXtended Facebook Markup Language). XFBML is a set of XML elements that can be included in your HTML pages to display Social Plugins. When your page is loaded, any XFBML elements found in the document are processed by the JavaScript SDK, resulting in the appropriate plugin being rendered on your page. The JavaScript SDK will continue to support XFBML after the deprecation of FBML (save for the fb:serverFbml element which is used to execute FBML on our servers).

Source : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do what you're wanting to do with the HTML5 version. You're Javascript will look something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // CUSTOM LISTENING CODE, or anything else using FB.something, goes below

    // SAMPLE LISTENING CODE

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );
    FB.Event.subscribe('message.send',
        function(response) {
            alert('You sent the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );

    // END SAMPLE LISTENING CODE

};
```

Note that you'll also have to set up a channel file, explained in the [Facebook Javascript SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). But having properly initialized the Javascript SDK, and then remembering to include all `FB.something` code in the `window.fbAsyncInit` function, you absolutely can detect when the HTML5 like button is pressed.

Comment: @Tosh: The above code definitely does work for detecting when the HTML5 like button is pressed.